# in bpy, using bpy.data.libraries.load, how can I access the remote scene object?

Tags: python, keyframes, library

I made a bpy script to load a remote blender file with

```
bpy.data.libraries.load
```

I've been able to access remote objects, materials and keyframes associated to copy them to my main blender file with a custom process.

I've figure out that theses remote objects may have relative parentality with objects that alters their locations.

My new copy strategy is to copy frame-by-frame objects locations.

So I need to know how much frames the remote blender file have (in the scene) and also a way to iterate over each frame of this remote scene.